# 3rd parties won't reconize WP installation

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem where the wordpress app, IFTTT and other 3rd parties won't recogize my wordpress installation.

Does anyone know what the problem may be?

[Application error](http://pastebin.com/4aDRStsM)

Comment: Do you have any errors returned, and is the WP installation public facing?

Comment: The errormessage is "This is not a valid Wordpress url", and the site is working perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have php7.0-xml installed....